# Load on MYSQL-backed page

Tags: php, mysql, caching, indexing, load-testing

I've got a page which makes 4 SQL calls(2 SELECTs, 1 INSERT, and an UPDATE) to 2 different MYSQL tables each time it loads.

The page is coded in PHP without any caching. I expect the size of each table to grow to about 30,000 rows and haven't load tested. The SELECT queries will pull 5 rows max per query.

What can I do to prevent the db from crashing under too much load. Will adding indices to the tables which correspond to the columns referenced in my queries help?

Comment: If you're running selects on values that don't change often, you can cache them on the server to prevent running the same query for the same data every time.

Comment: Well, since you've not posted any code, database schema, data, or really anything useful or pertinent to anyone being able to provide you with a real answer... then yes. 30k rows is a small database and, assuming that you've designed it and the queries *properly*, everything will be sunshine and rainbows.

Comment: "I... haven't load tested... What can I do to prevent the db from crashing under too much load"  You should probably proceed with load testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 30,000 rows isn't a lot of data; the database should be able to easily handle that much.

If the `SELECT`s are repetitive, the query cache, which you should have enabled, will probably cache them, so the load from those will be negligible.  You should almost always have indexes on the columns you are filtering and sorting on, so make sure your queries are using indexes.

If you don't need the data from the `INSERT`s instantly, you can use `INSERT DELAYED`, which will queue up inserts until the table is unused and insert all waiting rows at the same time.  Unless you're expecting to consistently have multiple `INSERT`s per second, using `INSERT DELAYED` probably won't make a noticeable difference.

Make sure the `UPDATE`s are using indexes, too.

To say anything more specific, we'd need more information like the structure of the DB and code.

Comment: Thanks man. I know I wasn't being too specific but this was the kind of info I was looking for.